# Setup up c# to save to local database when offline and update/send to mysql when online

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making a application in c# for windows that is for field guys to mark what they did on a job. there is a proposal side to this that sales guys put in the proposal and it saves to a MySQL database. The proposal is all done online and is PHP. What my issue is the field guys will not always have internet available to them when they are filling out what they do so I need a way for them to be able to see what the proposal is for and then fill out what they did and save it locally. Then when internet is available for it to update the online MySQL with what they did. I am looking at exporting the proposal to XML and emailing it to the field person so my hope is they can import it into the c# and see what they are suppose to be doing. Then do the job filling out what they really did and send it back to the database once online.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach.  Is there a question or did you just want to share?

Comment: question is how can this be done?

Comment: i guess really my question is there a better way then the xml file to do this and does it make since to edit the xml file is that is the best way or install mysql on each field guys laptop and import/export that that?

Comment: What does "it" in "... for it to update the online MySQL" refer to? Field guys? How are they to do that? If "The proposal ... is PHP" means this is a web site, why not have the web site do the updating? Where does C# enter the picture, is there some kind of application you haven't told us about? If there's a web site and/or an application, why would you need to send an email?

Comment: the proposal is a website made in php, the application i am making is c# windows app. The issue is the field guys are out and about and do not always have internet access so they cant just log on the site. The guys can be miles from the office so the email would be used to send them the next job. so the idea is the field guy is out and sales makes a proposal the director would email that to the field guy as a link or file and it would load in the c# app. so the field guy can see what he gets to do next(based on the proposal he is sent) so it to update the online when the field guys gets online

Comment: the work he logged in the local*database, flatfile, xml file* is sent to the online database and the rows there are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would require the guys to have local MYSQL instances installed, another option would be to use microsoft synchronization services for .net from within the c# application.

Most [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384472.aspx) you will find are for MS SQL, it works with anything that has an ado.net provider as illustrated [here](http://www.syncguru.com/projects/SyncServicesDemoOracle.aspx) with Oracle.

Comment: Thank you Rie819 I will play with the examples and see what i come up with. I don't mind installing mysql on everything if this works right .

Comment: Another quick question but do you know how to setup the remote update/select/insert for mysql with it online the only hostname i can find is localhost

Comment: @bmorrison1982 I must confess, I've never had the need to use synchronization services, it's just something I've kept an eye on because I'm sure I'll be asked to do something like what your doing right now. Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938879.aspx#UsingCompressiontoReduceDataTransferVolumesoverWCF it describes how to enable compression for WCF and synchronization services. It should be a good place to start.  I definitely recommend setting up a service of some variety for your clients as they will need to connect to your servers via the web.

Comment: thank you rie819 i found my answer I still have not been able to get the sync services to work with mysql but its getting closer.